# DIV Layout and positioning

Tags: html, positioning

I'm struggling to position a input button and then form field to the right of a DIV.

You can see the basic layout here : http://jsfiddle.net/qk0jp5pt/

```
body { background-color:#C0C0C0; }
#page { width: 80%; margin: 30px auto; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #800000 }   
#row { width: 80%; border: 1px solid #FF0000; }                                                                                                                                                                   
#table { width: 80%; border: 1px solid #00FF00 }
```

The `#row` is the div I'm trying to align. It's border is red and I'd like to move the input button the right inside of that DIV.

Ultimately I'd like to add an input text field and have them both aligned to the right with in `#row`.
http://jsfiddle.net/qk0jp5pt/1/

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong !

Thanks

Comment: How can #table and #row both have a width of 80%?

Comment: You mean something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/utq26ww4/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

`text-align: right;`

to `#row` does the trick

http://jsfiddle.net/qk0jp5pt/2/

Comment: @BigChris: then add them in another container, a form or a div and apply the `text-align: right;` css property only to that container

Comment: Great thanks.. Thought I'd tried that but must have made a mistake !

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Float for div content or inputs.

```
    float: right;
```